# IF e ELSE se o arquivo for PDF ou DOCX

Tags: php

Eu tenho um sisteminha, aonde arquivos (docx e pdf) mensais são cadastrados, **para eu visualizar no navegador os arquivos docx** tive que utilizar um `iframe`, e agora consigo visualizar os docx, **mas não consigo mais visualizar os PDF...**

Estava pensando em utilizar um `IF` e `ELSE`, mas não sei como diferenciar os arquivos...

> Para entender melhor: *Se o arquivo for **DOCX** abrir o arquivo por esse caminho, Se não, por esse caminho...*

*Eu redireciono os arquivos para a pagina (ver-arquivo.php) para serem abertos.*

**Aonde os arquivos são enviados:**

```
echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsed/{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/bola.png' style='width:40px; height:40px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";


                echo $cont['relatorio_enfermagem'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsenf/{$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/enf.png' style='width:40px; height:40px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

                     echo $cont['relatorio_nutricao'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsnut/{$cont['relatorio_nutricao']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_nutricao']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/nut.png' style='width:40px; height:40px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

                       echo $cont['relatorio_pedagogia'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsped/{$cont['relatorio_pedagogia']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_pedagogia']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/ped.png' style='width:45px; height:45px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

                          echo $cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadster/{$cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/ter.png' style='width:45px; height:45px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

                         echo $cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadser/{$cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/ser.png' style='width:45px; height:45px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";
```

**Código aonde eu visualizo os arquivos docx:** (ver-arquivo.php)

```
<iframe class="arquivos" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://www.meusite.com/<?php echo urlencode($_GET['documento']); ?>"></iframe>
```

**Código de como eu conseguia visualizar os arquivos pdf:**

```
<a href='uploads/uploadsenf/".$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']."'target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']."</a>
```

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer isso com `IF` e `ELSE`, ou alguma outra função?

Comment: onde esses arquivos tao salvos?

Comment: O caminho dos arquivos ficam salvos no banco e os arquivos em si em diretório

Comment: Vamos lá, o que eu iria fazer é o seguinte: criar uma white list contendo as extensões permitidas e apos isto usar uma das seguintes funções: 

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php
 - 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Eu não lhe dei o código do IF pronto, ontem no chat? Este https://pastebin.com/raw/JUrZZfRN

Comment: Eai Guilherme, não funcionou, ai você teve que sair

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `pathinfo()`, com ela você terá algumas informações sobre o arquivo. E uma delas é a extensão. Você pode obter mais informações sobre essa função neste [link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php).

```
// Cria um array contendo os caminhos dos arquivos.
// Uma dica é que você pode aproveitar e colocar os icones para exibi-los dentro do laço
$data = [
    [
        'path' => 'relatorio_educacao_fisica',
        'icon' => 'images/icon/bola.png',
    ],
    [
        'path' => 'relatorio_enfermagem',
        'icon' => 'images/icon/enf.png',
    ],
    [
        'path' => 'relatorio_nutricao',
        'icon' => 'images/icon/nut.png',
    ]
];


foreach ($data as $value) {
    // Verifica se o caminho está "setado"
    if (isset($value['path'])) {
        // Pega a extensão do arquivo
        $extension = pathinfo($value['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($extension == 'pdf') {
            // Exibe o link com o icone correto para cada arquivo
            echo "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsenf/{$value['path']}' title='{$value['path']}' target='_blank'><img src='{$value['icon']}' style='width:40px; height:40px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>";
        } else {
            // Exibe seu iframe
            echo '<iframe class="arquivos" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://www.meusite.com/' . urlencode($value['path']) . '"></iframe>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<td></td>';
    }
}
```

> Tentei aproximar o meu exemplo ao máximo possível do seu código, mas preciso que você entenda o que o código faz, por isso não tente apenas copiar e colar o código e esperar que ele funcione.

Comment: um foreach percorrendo diretorios.

Comment: Como assim 6 diretórios? Por favor tenta colocar o exemplo do código, com isso fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Possuem 6 campos para cadastros de arquivos, cada campo tem o seu diretório.

Comment: A ideia do Arthur é uma boa. Mas se possível coloca o trecho do código ai, fica mais fácil pra gente te ajudar.

Comment: Já coloquei, sou novo em programação e fico um pouco confuso....

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta para tentar resolver da melhor forma.

Comment: No aguardo.....